# Copy data from self-hosted Integration runtime to azure data lake?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data, using the copy activity in a synapse-pipeline, from a self hosted integration runtime rest api call to a azure data lake gen2. Using preview I can see the data from the rest api call but when I try to do the copy activity it is queued endlessly. Any idea why this happens? The Source is working with a self hosted integration Runtime and the Sink with azure integration runtime. Could this be the problem? Otherwise both connections are tested and working...

Edit: When trying the the web call, it tells me it's processing for a long time but I know I can connect to the rest api source since when using the preview feature in the copy activity it shows me the response....

Running the diagnostic tool, I receive the following error:
[image]

It seems to be a problem with the certificate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Integration runtime**

If you use a Self-hosted Integration Runtime (IR) and copy activity waits long in the queue until the IR has available resource to execute, suggest scaling out/up your IR.

If you use an Azure Integration Runtime that is in a not optimal region resulting in slow read/write, suggest configuring to use an IR in another region.

You can also try [performance tuning tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#performance-tuning-tips)

---

> how do i scale up the IR?

[Scale Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#scale-considerations)

Comment: how do i scale up the IR? In Azure or on the machine where its installed?

Comment: CPU usage is around 4% and i have increased concurency but still the same

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: I updated my question, it seems to be certificate error. Do have any ideas how to solve this?